# Paypal - Recurring Donations URL

Tags: paypal

Paypal makes it really easy to create a donate URL. A donor can enter a custom $ amount or use a fixed one. We'll use the custom amount, since it's more flexible. Is there anyway to allow the donor to enter a custom amount, and have PayPal display a checkbox for example to allow this amount to be a recurring monthly donation via a URL?

We checked out the "subscribe" button, but it only returns a form, not a URL, and didn't see anywhere to let the donor choose the amount.

Basically, this should be an optional field in the donate URL. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use standard subscription buttons or the [Recurring Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#recurring).  Either way you could setup your page so the user chooses those options on your site prior to being sent over to PayPal.

Comment: I need the final output to be a URL, not an HTML form. This is really important as I can only use a URL in my situation, which needs to include an optional recurring donation option, once on the PayPal payment page.

Comment: If you start with a standard subscription form you should then be able to turn it into a URL by taking the param names and values and appending them to the URL that the form would post to as URL params.

Comment: So I was able to get a fixed $ amount to recur by not filling out any 'customize button' $ fields (dropdowns with prices). Instead, I used the 'Billing amount each cycle', but the issue is it's an amount set in stone. Where as I want to enable the donor to customize the amount they want to donate by having paypal show an entry amount to donate and the typed amount will be 'recurring'. This is what I'm after. (I tried appending the URL form post, but that doesn't work on the select dropdown prices, as the donor has no flexibility to change the amounts on PayPal to recur)

Comment: I simply need to have a custom amount to be entered on paypal, for a recurring donation, in a form of a direct URL

Answer (score 0):

use `cmd=_donations`.  Paypal will prompt for an amount and whether it is recurring.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal now has recurring donations, for mobile checkout, by default. See [this blog post](https://gmg.cm/blog/is-paypal-now-providing-recurring-donations-on-mobile).